# For python, how to reset a global variable after I called certain function?

Tags: python, global-variables

I need one global variable s = set() to help me with certain recursive function. After I ran the function, I want it to be an empty set again. Is there any simple way for me to do it? I'm using python 3.4.1

ADD: So I want to traverse a tree to get the number of distinct nodes. In order to do that I use a global variable SET = set() to keep records of the same nodes. After I called the function, I want to reset the global variable SET.

```
SET = set()
def distinct_node_count(root):  
global SET
if not root.children:
    if root.value.__repr__() not in SET:
        SET.add(root.value.__repr__())
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
else:
    if root.value.__repr__() not in SET:
        SET.add(root.value.__repr__())
        return 1 + sum([distinct_node_count(child) for child in root.children]) 
    else: 
        return sum([distinct_node_count(child) for child in root.children])
```

Comment: It would help if you told us the purpose of the function.

Comment: can you add an example of the function

Comment: I added my function. It works but I need to reset the global variable every time I used it.

Comment: by the way unless really good reason you should store id(root) instead of roor.__repr__()

Answer (score 1):

don't use a global variable but a paramater with a default value

something like this

```
def recursive(oneparam, secondparam,*, s=None):

    if s is None:
        s = set()
    if secondparam < 0:
        return 0
    return 1 + recursive(oneparam,secondparam-1,s=s)
```

The previous version don't change really the contract but if you absolutly don't want to be able to add an additional parameter just use an auxiliary function

```
def recursive(oneparam, secondparam):
    def inner(oneparam, secondparam, s):
         if secondparam < 0:
             return 0
         return 1 + inner(oneparam,secondparam-1,s)
   inner(oneparam,secondparam,set())
```

Comment: I can only use one parameter in this function.....I can not change the type contract. One question though, wouldn't the default variable s be recreated when I call the recursive function?

Comment: both way to not change the contract (implicetly and explictly added)